# HP Proliant BL460C power supply converter

Tags: hp-proliant, power-supply-unit

I have 3 HP Proliant BL460C servers, but I don't have chassis for them. Is there any kind of power adapter that I can use for, so I can just use normal power cable to plugin? It's not for production, only for testing.

I did some search but could not find anything, any suggestion please?[image]

Comment: thank you for your question, I am not going to get into this trap... off-topic, but life-saver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to imagine circumstances where one would want to power on a blade server without the chassis.

The connector at the back of the blade server is not just a power connector. This connector includes 16 14Gbps SerDes lanes for midplane connection that can run different network protocols or external PCI-Express connections, connection to the power backplane and lights-out management.

Physically this is a MOLEX 75360-0018.It has exactly 100 data pins. Some of them would be used for the 16 SerDes lanes mentioned above, additional pins  would be used for power connection, yet most data pins are probably not used in your BL460. However the midplane is passive and has all 100 pins routed.

I have talked to HPC enthusiasts who were thinking of designing custom modules to fit into the C7000 chassis. Such a project could not be started without a detailed knowledge of the midplane and backplane topology. Yet this information is not widely available. If you really need it and have the necessary competences, you might contact HP for information.

Comment: Good information, though. That would be an interesting project.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to NopeNopeNope, may I ask how you ended up in this situation?

In order to use a blade server, you need a blade enclosure/chassis to house it. Remember, you need networking and storage and other things available to make that a usable system.

Comment: I dont want to buy a chassis at home for few retired servers, so just trying to find a workaround....

Comment: There's no workaround. Think about it: How would you connect these to a network?

Comment: looks like have to give up....

Comment: @RootLoop Also this server isn't for home-based questions as we make VERY clear when you sign up!

Comment: @Chopper3 some home setups are far superior to some office setups. It's all relative.

Comment: Irrelevant, read the rules.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

My advice is to get a chassis or stop what you're doing and re-evaluate why you're trying to do it.

Comment: I got few retired server at home, but I have no chassis, so just trying to find a workaround to power it up....looks like there is no way to do it....

Comment: In the odd event you missed it when you signed up (in which case, RTFM), this site is for *professionals* doing things in a *business* environment. Also, no you can't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @GregL Some professionals experiment with gear at home before they roll it out in a business context. So.. Whatever.

Comment: @JamesTSnell getting a little lonely under the bridge were we?

Comment: @GregL I've got wifi and power under here, so no.. Not so lonely. The espresso is terrible though, so.. There's that misfortune.